# WorkManager executing every time when I install (run) app

Tags: android, performance, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I have created two Worker through **WorkManager**. Its settled for every 30 minutes after I logged in successfully.

Once I logged in, Its started successfully and working as expected.

#### MyWorker.java

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: Done");

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

#### Starting worker when login successfully.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("Location")
            .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Location", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, periodicWork);
```

#### Problem:

When I run my app, its executing again. Its happening every time when I install (run) my app.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you please comment before down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio to install and run your application, that gets classified as a force stop.

If your app uses PeriodicWork, we need to reschedule all work. So it will run every time the app process is force stopped by Studio.

Comment: I am using Android Studio, is there any reason that why its stopping?

Comment: On which device are you seeing this?
Can you test on the emulator to verify that you see the same issue?

Comment: I am using Samsung device. I have tried on Emulator too.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you're using to enqueue the Worker classes?
What I meant in my reply is that, if you launch the app through Android Studio and then you stop it from there, it's marked as a forced stop and all the works are removed from the underlying JobScheduler API. when you relaunch the app, WorkManager retrieves the WorkRequest from its database and it restart the Work. But I need more information on how you are launching/stopping the app and the code that you're using to be sure that this is what it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` instead of `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE`

According to [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager):

> `REPLACE` ensures that if there is pending work labelled with
> `uniqueWorkName`, it will be cancelled and the new work will run.
> `KEEP` will run the new `PeriodicWorkRequest` only if there is no
> pending work labelled with `uniqueWorkName`.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if your workermanager is running a periodic task. If you can add a check by a flag in sharedpreference or something to check if the process has already started. Otherwise you will have to uninstall and then run it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.addTag("Location")` line.
Change the ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy attribute from REPLACE to KEEP.
Keep the rest of the code as is. This one should work fine for you.

Check out [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work) to learn more.